# Launch application on 3.5 inches mode on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have this app that I want to launch on my iPhone 5 but I want it to launch on 3.5inches format, with black bars up and down. I know I can use the 3.5" simulator but it will not work for me because the app uses the camera.

Ok I can launch it on the iPad but I really want to launch it on the iPhone.

OK, I can remove the 568h default image and it will launch, but I am trying to keep the project original.

Is there a way to pass some launch parameter to force the application to think it is running on a 3.5 inch device on iPhone 5?

Comment: Why run the app in 3.5" mode?

Comment: to test the screen elements?

Comment: But why not run it in full mode? Most likely, the app will work well.

Comment: nothing like checking all possibilities instead of trusting that it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. If you have the 568 launch image, it will launch using the entire screen.

Comment: Damn. I was suspecting that. Thanks.